# How to send scheduled custom message using Amazon EventBridge

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-event-bridge

I'm trying to build an Amazon EventBridge rule that runs on a schedule(weekly), to put an event in the SQS.
There are multiple options to choose from, as to what message is to be sent as an event.

I understand that it's essentially a JSON object, which can be set to a custom JSON, or the default(or some seletive fields from this) Something like:

```
{
  "version": "0",
  "id": "6a7e8feb-b491-4cf7-a9f1-bf3703467718",
  "detail-type": "EC2 Instance State-change Notification",
  "source": "aws.ec2",
  "account": "111122223333",
  "time": "2017-12-22T18:43:48Z",
  "region": "us-west-1",
  "resources": [
    "arn:aws:ec2:us-west-1:123456789012:instance/i-1234567890abcdef0"
  ],
  "detail": {
    "instance-id": " i-1234567890abcdef0",
    "state": "terminated"
  }
}
```

- AWS EventBridge: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-create-rule-schedule.html
- EB Events: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-events.html

My question is: **How can I send a JSON Object that has a different parameters every time?**

Say I want to publish this object, with a date-range different, with

- `activeFrom`: Today-7 days
- `activeTill`: Today's date.

```json
{
  "dummyId": "xyz",
  "activeFrom": "2021-07-09T18:43:48Z",
  "activeTill": "2021-07-15T18:43:48Z"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can let the EventBridge trigger a lambda function on schedule. In that lambda, you can bake your JSON and send the event to SQS.